# Construct cypher to add many relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wanted to add relationships to existing nodes, so I made cypher like this:

```
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='0'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='1') create n1-[:{quantity:1}]->n2;

start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='2') create n1-[:USES_COMPONENT{quantity:7}]->n2;

start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='3') create n1-[:USES_COMPONENT{quantity:11}]->n2;

start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='4') create n1-[:USES_COMPONENT{quantity:14}]->n2;
```

but got many error messages (`error around> {quantity`). When I add only one of those, it says `[[ Index` `node_auto_index` `does not exist ]]`.

Comment: you should not use node_auto_index but rather create your nodes with a label, e.g. `:Component` and create `index on :Component(id);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a relationship without a type. If you add a type to the first statement, e.g. `USES_COMPONENT` like the others, that should resolve the error. You can match a relationship without using its type, but you can't create it without a type. If you want to match it without type, then you also need to drop the `:`, i.e.

```
n1-[{quantity:1}]->n2
```

is a valid pattern.

With regards to index, how have you configured your `node_auto_index`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you don't have an index by that name.  Usually you could fix this by [enabling node auto-indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/auto-indexing.html#auto-indexing-config) -- Which is OK, but there's a better way to write your query:

```
MATCH (n0), (n1), (n2), (n3), (n4)
WHERE id(n0)=0 AND id(n1)=1 AND id(n2)=2 AND id(n3)=3 AND id(n4)=4
CREATE (n0)-[:USES_COMPONENT { quantity: 1 }]->(n1),
       (n1)-[:USES_COMPONENT { quantity: 7 }]->(n2),
       (n1)-[:USES_COMPONENT { quantity: 11}]->(n3),
       (n1)-[:USES_COMPONENT { quantity: 14}]->(n4)
RETURN n0, n1, n2, n3, n4;
```

It's easier to use `MATCH` along with a `WHERE` clause to find a particular node (in general).   Also notice that you can create as many new relationships as you want with a single query.

Double check this query before you use it -- you were re-using the `n2` variable in confusing ways, so you need to make sure I got the right IDs bound to the right nodes for you.

Comment: Thank you! I have 3 type of node labels.. Product, Component and Sub_Component .. Like your way, it's ok to add relationships for
(product)-[:relationships]-> (component) , bcoz I have only 6 Components. But for Relationships (component)-[:relationships]-> (Sub_Component) is not so good. There are too many (sub_Component) nodes.. I have to make manually? Is there better way?

Comment: Rather than using id(), you should assign nodes your own ID.  Then match them based on both label like `:Sub_Component` AND on their ID.